# Why are my images not displaying properly on my web page?

Tags: html, css, web, nuxt.js, nuxt3

So right now I am trying to make a staff page for a website for me and a few friends. Right now I am having an issue where my images on the staff page are not being shown properly. My components folder is on the same layer as my assets folder, but this is the only file where images aren't showing. my staffdata.vue file is as follows:

```
<!--staffdata.vue-->
  <template>
    <div class="staff">
      <h1>Meet Our Staff</h1>
      <div class="staff-list">
        <div v-for="staffMember in staffMembers" :key="staffMember.id" class="staff-member">
          <img :src="staffMember.image" alt="Staff Image" class="staff-image" />
          <div class="staff-details">
            <h2>{{ staffMember.name }}</h2>
            <p class="position">{{ staffMember.position }}</p>
            <p class="bio">{{ staffMember.bio }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        staffMembers: [
          {
            id: 0,
            name: 'L4w1i3t',
            position: 'Site Developer/Admin',
            bio: 'place',
            image: '../assets/images/lawliet'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'TuneEternal',
            position: 'Content Creator',
            bio: 'place',
            image: '../assets/images/xavier.png'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'JayQilin',
            position: 'Content Creator',
            bio: 'place',
            image: '../assets/images/qilin.png'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Savage Sentral',
            position: 'Content Creator',
            bio: 'place',
            image: '../assets/images/savage.png'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'IrisCandy',
            position: 'Artist',
            bio: 'place',
            image: '../assets/images/iris.png'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Matsuda Akai',
            position: 'Mascot',
            bio: 'place',
            image: '/assets/images/red.png'
          },
        ]
      };
    }
  };
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  .staff {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .staff-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .staff-member {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.staff-image {
  /* Remove the predefined width and height */
  /* width: 150px; 
  height: 150px; */

  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  object-fit: contain; /* Display the image in its original dimensions */
}

.staff-details {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.position {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.bio {
  color: #333;
}
  </style>
```

[image: and here is the structure of my layers:]

any help is appreciated, I have been going at this for an hour now.

Comment: What do mean by "properly"? As in not showing at all, not the right size etc

Comment: They do not appear at all, no matter how I change the dimensions, ordering in the layout, or size. There's only a usual placeholder thing that typically shows in the absence of media, so I know that my code is trying to pull *something*, but no images are actually showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is occurd because of image's path.

For example,  `../assets/images/qilin.png` : this path is image path that calcuated from `staffdata.vue`file.

But after file rendered, image path calculated from public folder.

So, to solve this problem, you can move assets folder to public folder and remove `../` from image url.
Like this : `assets/images/gilin.png`

Hope to help you .

Comment: this helped, thank you! I had to change a few other directories across my pages to adhere to moving assets into public, but otherwise things are appearing as intended now. Curious, though; why did that happen on just that one component when the rest of the components were completely fine pulling from the same directory?

Comment: I think `img` is special tag.  Most attributes like `id` and `class` work and are set while rendering but `src` attribute of `img` tag works after rendered. so it works when directory structure changed.(after all components merged into one `index.html` so there are no independent directories for `src`)